# How to hide an activity after login in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have developed an App where the user has to login into the app using the login Activity. After successful login, the app is directed to Activity B. The app doesn't provide any signout options.So next time when the user uses the app I want to hide the login Activity's layout. Is it possible to do so?If yes, how is it possible?

Comment: Use shared preference and store detail in it, then check if the preference is empty then open login activity other wise second activity.

Comment: If you want any example then please post your code i will help you.

Comment: Also call the `finish()` method on the Activity A once you are done with it, so that the user can't go back to Activity A once in Activity B.

Answer (score 3):

In LoginActivity do as Suggested by nr4bt but instead of **int** Put & get **Boolean** Value in SharedPreference.

write this code

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putValue("loginStatus", true);
editor.commit();
```

& onCreate() of LoginActivity Write this code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getBoolean("loginStatus", false);
if (restoredText == true) {
 // start activity
  finish(); // destroy login so user can't come back with back button
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a variable in sharedpreferences and check it when your login activity starts

in LoginActivity, when the user press login button and if success,

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putInt("loginStatus", 1);// removed "" 
 editor.commit();
```

Then in onCreate check the variable,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
int restoredText = prefs.getInt("loginStatus", 0);
if (restoredText == 1) {
  // start activity
  finish(); // destroy login so user can't come back with back button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to achive with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You just save that user has loged in and later on start check if he already done it or not and act properly.