# Android app user login activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an internal-use Android app which requires users to always login. My app consists of a dashboard which will have 4 available actions on it to perform.

What is the best practice? Set LoginActivity to be the main activity, or use the DashboardActivity as the main and on startup show login screen if user is not logged?

Thanks!

Comment: So you basically want to login a user the first time then remember it for next time?

Comment: No. Just remember it as longs as the app is running.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the login activity and use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to pass on the username once the user logs in correctly to the app for the first time. The user would remain logged in until he logs out of it (either manually or by deleting the app data from the phone settings).

The function of the SharedPrefences is to keep the user details in the app, even after the user goes to a different app. The credentials are kept when he/she uses them again once the user uses the app again. If you have developed for web applications beforehand, it is somewhat similar to the function of cookies, only more secure, since these credentials are kept hidden in the app.

A very good tutorial on how to implement [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html).

You can use the first loginActivitiy for the first time a user logs in. Then once the user returns to the app, he/she would be taken to the main page of the app (the next activity after a login is successful). This can be achieved though a few lines of code as in [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/21952752/1116216) post.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it has helped you?